# jQuery/RegEx - Return all but last number?

Tags: jquery, regex, google-chrome

I have a string as follows:

```
Some:7 Stuff " x 3 "
```

I have the following RegEx:

```
/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/g
```

It correctly grabs the `3` from the string, but I need it to grab *everything else* so I can `.replace()` it. I essentially need the inverse of it, but how do I go about doing this?

I want ONLY the 3 to remain after running .replace(). Currently it removes the 3.

EDIT: Relevant code [here](https://gist.github.com/n4ru/f899e15ac977d662a321).

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: So you want to get the two matches `Some:7 Stuff " x ` and `"`?

Comment: I want to replace everything BUT the 3 in my string. I want 3 to be returned after running replace on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to `match` rather than replacing?

```
'Some:7 Stuff " x 3 "'.match(/(\d+)(?=[^\d]*$)/).pop(); //3
```

I'm not entirely sure if the regex will fit your needs in all cases, since I do not know your needs, but that's just for this exemple.

If the last number is really the only thing you want to keep, I see it more like getting something from the string rather than a replace.

Comment: Slipped my mind completely! Solved my issue with this:
`match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/g, '$1')`

Thank you!

Comment: @Thirk I'm glad I could help. However, note that match doesn't take 2 arguments. Also, the global flag is unecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This should match your expectations:

```
var str = 'Some:7 Stuff " x 3 "';
console.log(str.replace(/^.*?(\d+)[^\d]*$/, '$1'));
```

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but running `$(elemthree, this).text().replace(/^.*?(\d+)[^\d]*$/, '$1')`, returns

`Some:7 Stuff

x 3`

Only removing the quotes.

Comment: Are you trying to change the text inside the element?

Comment: No, I'm taking the data to put inside an array. Here is the relevant code: https://gist.github.com/n4ru/f899e15ac977d662a321

Answer (score 0):

Use regex replace:

```
'Some:7 Stuff " x 3 "'.replace(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/g, "NEW_VALUE"); 
 // gets "Some:7 Stuff " x NEW_VALUE ""
```